# ARM926ej-s reset handler - does it overwrite itself?

Tags: assembly, stack, arm

I know that ARM926ej-s is using **full descending** stack. Now I have this startup code in which i have comented using `/**/` on lines that are relevant for this question.

```
.global __start
.global arm926ejs_reset
.global dcache_flush
.global __gnu_bssstart
.global __gnu_bssend
.global __image_size


.EQU MODE_USR,    0x010
.EQU MODE_FIQ,    0x011
.EQU MODE_IRQ,    0x012
.EQU MODE_SVC,    0x013
.EQU MODE_SVC_NI, 0x0D3
.EQU MODE_ABORT,  0x017
.EQU MODE_UNDEF,  0x01b
.EQU MODE_SYSTEM, 0x01f
.EQU MODE_BITS,   0x01f
.EQU I_MASK,      0x080
.EQU F_MASK,      0x040
.EQU IF_MASK,     0x0C0

.EQU BROM_MMU_BASE_ADDR, 0x1201C000 

.EQU MMU_DISABLE_MASK,   0xFFFFEFFA
.EQU MMU_ENABLE_MASK,    0x00001005

.EQU FIQ_STACK_SIZE,     128
.EQU IRQ_STACK_SIZE,     256
.EQU ABORT_STACK_SIZE,   32
.EQU UNDEF_STACK_SIZE,   32
.EQU SYSTEM_STACK_SIZE,  64

.text
.code 32
.align 2

__start:
arm926ejs_reset:
    B     arm926ejs_reset_handler     /*reset vector*/

.word   0x41676d69
.word   0,0,0,0,0
image_type:
.word   0x0000000A
sizeOfPermanentCode:    
    .word   (__image_size)
    .word   0,0
bootparameter:  
    .word   0
    .word   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

arm926ejs_reset_handler:

    MOV   r0, #MODE_SVC_NI
    MSR   cpsr_cxsf, r0

    MRC   p15, 0, r1, c1, c0, 0
    LDR   r2,=MMU_DISABLE_MASK
    AND   r1, r1, r2
    MCR   p15, 0, r1, c1, c0, 0

    MOV   r1,#0
    MCR   p15, 0, r1, c8, c7, 0

    MCR   p15, 0, r1, c7, c7, 0

    MRC   p15, 0, r1, c1, c0, 0
    LDR   r2,=0x1000
    ORR   r1, r1, r2
    MCR   p15, 0, r1, c1, c0, 0

    MVN   r1, #0
    MCR   p15, 0, r1, c3, c0, 0

    LDR   r3, =BROM_MMU_BASE_ADDR
    MCR   p15, 0, r3, c2, c0, 0

    LDR   r5, =inVirtMem

    MRC   p15, 0, r1, c1, c0, 0
    LDR   r2,=MMU_ENABLE_MASK
    ORR   r1, r1, r2
    MCR   p15, 0, r1, c1, c0, 0

    MOV   pc, r5

    NOP
    NOP
    NOP

inVirtMem:
    ADR   r3, arm926ejs_reset         /*we store the reset vector address*/
    SUB   r3, r3, #4                  /*why do we then substract 4 bytes?*/
    MOV   r1, #IF_MASK

    ORR   r0, r1, #MODE_FIQ           /*sets stack for MCPU mode*/
    MSR   cpsr_cxsf, r0
    MOV   sp, r3                 
    SUB   r3, r3, #FIQ_STACK_SIZE


    ORR   r0, r1, #MODE_IRQ           /*sets stack for MCPU mode*/
    MSR   cpsr_cxsf, r0
    MOV   sp, r3
    SUB   r3, r3, #IRQ_STACK_SIZE

    ORR   r0, r1, #MODE_ABORT         /*sets stack for MCPU mode*/ 
    MSR   cpsr_cxsf, r0
    MOV   sp, r3
    SUB   r3, r3, #ABORT_STACK_SIZE

    ORR   r0, r1, #MODE_UNDEF         /*sets stack for MCPU mode*/
    MSR   cpsr_cxsf, r0
    MOV   sp, r3
    SUB   r3, r3, #UNDEF_STACK_SIZE

    ORR   r0, r1, #MODE_SYSTEM        /*sets stack for MCPU mode*/
    MSR   cpsr_cxsf, r0
    MOV   sp, r3
    SUB   r3, r3, #SYSTEM_STACK_SIZE

    ORR   r0, r1, #MODE_SVC           /*sets stack for MCPU mode*/
    MSR   cpsr_cxsf, r0
    MOV   sp, r3

    LDR   r0, =__gnu_bssstart
    LDR   r1, =__gnu_bssend
    MOV   r2, #0

clearzi:
    CMP   r0, r1
    BEQ   clearzi_exit
    STR   r2, [r0]
    ADD   r0, r0, #4
    B clearzi

clearzi_exit:

load_entry:
    LDR   pc, =c_entry
    NOP

dcache_flush:
    CMP   r0, #0
    BNE   inval

flushonly:
    MRC  p15, 0, r15, c7, c10, 3
    BNE  flushonly
    MOV  pc, lr

inval:
    MRC  p15, 0, r15, c7, c14, 3
    BNE  inval
    MOV  pc, lr

.END
```

In the code above the first comment shows a reset vector (a branching instruction `B arm926ejs_reset_handler`) immediately followed by a header and some commands to prepare the mcu...

Now take a look at the next comment where we store the reset vector's address into register `r3` and in the next line we substract the `4` bytes from this address.

**Q1:** Why do we do this? Does this address now show at the location of the `.word 0x41676d69` ?

In next lines there are multiple simmilar blocks and each sets the stack for different mcpu modes. Lets take a look at the first one where stack pointer `sp` is loaded with register `r3` and then the size of the stack is substracted from this address to get the stack size for this mcpu mode.

**Q2:** Does this stack overwrite the header from `.word 0x41676d69` on and all the instructions used to prepare the mcu? Does reset vector `B arm926ejs_reset_handler` stay intact? Why do we owerwrite header? Don't we need it anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now take a look at the next comment where we store the reset vector's address into register r3 and in the next line we substract the 4 bytes from this address.
>
> Q1: Why do we do this? Does this address now show at the location of the .word 0x41676d69 ?

Generally code increments.  So the value `.word 0x41676d69` is after or *arm926ejs_reset+4*.  When you subtract, you put the start of the *descending stack* just before the code memory.

> Q2: Does this stack overwrite the header from .word 0x41676d69 on and all the instructions used to prepare the mcu? Does reset vector B arm926ejs_reset_handler stay intact? Why do we owerwrite header? Don't we need it anymore?

No, it is not over-written.  The memory before the image is used for the stacks.

Comment: So when substracting 4 we move one line UP from the arm926ejs_reset? And when we then substract the stack size we move even further UP? I am still not sure of this. In ARM we have a full descending stack. I am not quite sure but when you mention "Image" do you mean header? I need to clear the terminology to myself a bit...

Comment: @71GA Image is binary you put on memory containing instructions. You need to setup stacks for different modes, so you start by using the area before instructions for FIQ, IRQ, ABORT, UNDEF, SYSTEM, SVC. And they do get placed before instruction area, because of the subtracting you do with SP.

Comment: What do you mean by instructions? .EQU MODE_USR, 0x010 .EQU MODE_FIQ,    0x011 .EQU MODE_IRQ, 0x012? I don't quite understand how can put stack s before these instructions because I only use -4 ...

Comment: In my case the entry point of the program has to be set to `0x11029000`and it is set to the label `__start`. Does this mean that substracting 4 sets the bottom of the stack to be at `0x11028FFC`?

Comment: I am allso guessing that commands before arm926ejs_reset will fall into .rodata section and i have to put this section on a higher address that .text section in order not to overwrite those constants with stacks?

Comment: The `.EQU MODE_USR, 0x10` is a *define*.  The `cpsr` (current program status register) contains the [ARM mode](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[arm]+mode+is%3Aquestion).  Each mode has [banked registers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[arm]+banked+is%3Aquestion).  Your address calculation of *0x11028FFC* is correct.  The `.word 0x41676d69` will be at *0x11029004*.  And you should not put anything before `.text` in your linker file (like `.rodata`), if you want this code to work.  You can reserve space in a linker file with `.stack (NOLOAD) : { . = . + 1k; _stack_top = .; }` with *ld*.

Comment: The `.rodata` should be after `.text`.  You need to be proficient in your *linker* if you want to modify start-up code.  The *assembler* and *linker* work together as a team when doing stuff like code relocation, setting up MMUs, stacks, etc. which is commonly done in start-up code.  You can often kludge things by using constants in assembler; but using the linker to do this is more elegant and less error prone.  Be sure to generate and examine a map file.

Comment: @artless noise so my guessing was correct =) Thank you for the clarification! How do I generate and examine a map file? This is the first time I hear of this.

Comment: So now i understand that all the defines will be put to .data sections. But what about directives like .code 32 .align 2 etc? Do these allso fall into .data?

Comment: The `.equ` is a define (also called a *directive*).  The `.align` and `.data` are other directives.  Like `#define` is different than `#include` or `#ifdef`.  If you use GNU, then [Binutil docs](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.23.1/) have answers; [Directives](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.23.1/as/Pseudo-Ops.html) and [ld options](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.23.1/ld/Options.html).  `-M` or `--print-map` makes a map file.  Please take a look at the documents.  Read both the `ld` and `as` directives; they make sense together, especially for *sections*.

Comment: I have read some of those already. Will look into it. Thank you very much.